# Getting Image to display in form - dll file

Tags: c#, jquery, node.js, vb.net, dll

I have a vb.net form application in which i have displayed a logo from Application startup path using the code

```
Application.StartupPath + ("\Image\" + "Logo.jpg")
```

This works and the image displayed as expected. This exe is called from jquery using AciveX and hence it works only in IE.

I have converted the vb.net form application to dll by referencing the exe created. Now, when i call the dll function from another application, the form appears but the logo is not displaying.

I have used edge to read dll files from node.js application.

Please help to get the image to be displayed in the form when reading using dll file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your image path at runtime to ensure it was resolving correctly?  If your dll is in a different folder than your calling application, Application.StartupPath may not resolve as expected.

I was having a similar problem, but referencing an image in my resources manager.  I realized when I transferred the form from an application solution to the dll solution, my PictureBox lost the default setting of its "Image" property in the designer, so it wasn't trying to set any image at all.